# Copy row in the database changing some data using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to create a new record in my tenants table only changing the tenantEmail and tenantPhone. The table has a lot of columns, so I think about doing something like that:

```
var getTenant = db.tenants.Where(x => x.TenantID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
tenant t = new tenant();
t = getTenant;
t.TenantEmail = "NEWEMAIL";
t.TenantPhone = "NEWPHONE";
// How can I insert this new tenant? Will it have the some TenantID (I don't want the same tenant id)?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.AsNoTracking()` and it will remove the association to the database and then you can change the few fields you need and leave all the others as they were and add it like a new object.  just set the ID field to null before you add it.

```
var getTenant = db.tenants
    .Where(x => x.TenantID == 1)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault();

... change your fields

   db.tenants.Add(getTenant)
```

Comment: I can't set ID to null because it is int type non-nullable

Answer (score 1):

I assume `db` is your `dbContext`

```
//If `TenantId` is your primary key
var tenant = dbContext.tenants.Find(_tenantId); 

//If not then use `where` to get the record from the database
var tenant = dbContext.tenants.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.TenantId==_tenantId);  

//Detach it from the context
dbContext.Entry(tenant).State = EntityState.Detached;

//add the new values and don't forget to set the primary key value to 0
tenant.TenantId=0;

tenant.TenantEmail = "NEWEMAIL";
tenant.TenantPhone = "NEWPHONE";

//Add it to the context
dbContext.Entry(tenant).State = EntityState.Added; 
//Or add it to tenants list
dbContext.tenants.Add(tenant);

//Create a new record by calling save changes
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: My primaryKey is autoincrement... Setting it to 0, will make it auto increment in the context.SaveChanges()?

Comment: When I try to do dbContext.tenants.Add(tenant), I got an error: The property 'TenantID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified